# Re-arrange in all posible orders all individual sublists withou t repetition

Tags: r

I would like to re-arrange the different sub-lists in all posible orders within a sub list without repetition.

```
x <- list ( c(1,3,2) , c(5,3,1) , c(3,5,1) )

require(gtools)
z <- permutations(n = length(x), r = 3) # all possible combinations are as follows. 

# Desired output

x1 <- list ( c(5,3,1) , c(1,3,2) , c(3,5,1) )
x2 <- list ( c(5,3,1) , c(3,5,1) , c(1,3,2) )  
x3 <- list ( c(1,3,2) , c(5,3,1) , c(3,5,1) )  
x4 <- list ( c(1,3,2) , c(3,5,1) , c(5,3,1) )   
x5 <- list ( c(3,5,1) , c(1,3,2) , c(5,3,1) )
x6 <- list ( c(3,5,1) , c(5,3,1) , c(1,3,2) )
```

Have tried with a regular function as the expresion of a list with sublists and calling the index z for permutations. So I get this fine however I dont know how to instruct for this without any of the segments repeating at the same time.

```
fun <- function (y) list (c(x[z[,1][y]]) , c(x[z[,1][y]]) , c(x[z[,1][y]]))
lapply ( seq ( nrow (z) ) , fun )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `apply()` over the rows of the permutation matrix:

```
x <- list ( c(1,3,2) , c(5,3,1) , c(3,5,1) )
library(gtools)
idx <- permutations(n = length(x), r = 3) # all possible combinations are as follows
perm <- apply(idx, 1, function(i) x[i])
```

The first permutation is then:

```
perm[1]
## [[1]]
## [[1]][[1]]
## [1] 1 3 2
## 
## [[1]][[2]]
## [1] 5 3 1
## 
## [[1]][[3]]
## [1] 3 5 1
```

And you can get the others similary.

If you care to have each permutation in its own variable, you can do this as follows:

```
for (i in seq_along(perm)) {
  assign(paste0("x", i), perm[i])
}
```

However, it is easier to work with a list than with separate variables.

Comment: What do you mean by "with repetition"? There are six permutations of 3 elements, and each one is contained in the list exactly once. And it corresponds to what you called "Desired output" in your question. Your question probably needs clarification.

Comment: My appologies you are right needs clarification upvote correct

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively use the `permn()` function from the `combinat` package.

```
library(combinat)

permn(x)
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] 1 3 2
#
#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] 5 3 1
#
#[[1]][[3]]
#[1] 3 5 1
```